# Simplify difference of two arctangents?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I have a problem, that I am trying to simplify, but there does not seem to be something obvious regarding it.

Very simply, I am trying to figure out if there is a way to 'open' the following:

$$
\tan^{-1} (\frac{a}{b}) - \tan^{-1} (\frac{c}{d})
$$

By 'open', I simply mean that I would like to be able to group $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ together somehow, so that I can continue with my work. I have scoured wiki for something that might allow me to do that, but could not find anything.

Disclaimer: I should also add that the $\tan^{-1}$ here refers to the 'Four Quadrant' inverse tangent, usually found in computer programs as 'atan2' instead of simply 'atan'.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation and play with all combinations of signs of $a,b,c,d$

Answer (score 3):

note that: $$\tan(\alpha-\beta )=\frac{\tan\alpha- \tan\beta }{1+\tan\alpha \tan\beta } $$ $$\Longrightarrow \alpha -\beta =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\alpha- \tan\beta }{1+\tan\alpha \tan\beta }\right).$$ Try letting $\alpha=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ and $\beta =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)$.  Then $\tan\alpha=\frac{a}{b}$ and $\tan\beta=\frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I will have to dig into it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface it seems counterintuitive, but

$$\arctan(a) - \arctan(b) = \frac 1 {2 \mathrm i} \ln \frac {(a-i)(b+i)} {(a+i)(a-b)} \ .$$

This can be found by utilizing partial fractions when computing the integral of $\dfrac 1 {x^2+1}$ instead of using inverse trigonometrical functions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find an expression for

$$ \tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big) - \tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{c}{d}\Big) $$

where $\,\tan^{-1}\,$ is expressed in terms of `atan2`. I think that the
easiest method is to notice that $\,\tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)
=\arg(b+ia)\,$ for real values of $\,a\,$ and $\,b.\,$ Thus, we get

$$ \tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big) - \tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{c}{d}\Big) =
\arg(b+ia) - \arg(d+ic) \equiv \arg\Big(\frac{b+ia}{d+ic}\Big) \pmod{2\pi}. $$

This can be simplified using

$$ \frac{b+ia}{d+ic} = \frac{(b+ia)(d-ic)}{d^2+c^2} = (bd+ac)+i(ad-bc) $$

with the final result that
$$ \arg\Big(\frac{b+ia}{d+ic}\Big) = \tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{ad-bc}{bd+ac}\Big). $$